# Show that $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^4)$ with det $T<0$ has at least two distinct eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

a) Suppose that $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^4)$ satisfies det $T < 0$. Show that $T$ has at least two distinct eigenvalues.

b) Find a $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^4)$ where det $T < 0$ such that $T$ has only one eigenvalue.

For a) I was thinking of trying to show a contradiction when $T$ has at most one distinct eigenvector, but I don't know where to go from here. Any help would be great.

Comment: @lhf Fixed thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P$ be the characteristic polynomial of $T$, $P(X)=(X-a)(X-b)(X-c)(X-d)$ where $a,b,c,d$ are eigenvalues, and $\det(T)=abcd$ suppose that $P$ has only complex eigenvalues, since the coefficients of $P$ are real $a$ and its conjugate $\bar a$ are eigenvalues, we deduce that $P=(X-a)(X-\bar a)(X-b)(X-\bar b)$ and $\det(T)=(|a||b|)^2$ contradiction. This implies that $P$ has a real eigenvalue $a$, if $a$ is the unique real value, $\det(T)=a^4>0$ contradiction.

For $b$ consider the $u=\sqrt[4]{-1}$ and $T(x)=ux$.

Answer (score 0):

(a) The characteristic polynomial $\chi$ has degree $4$ and so $\chi(x)>0$ for $x$ large. Now $\chi(0)=\det T <0$. Therefore $\chi$ has a real root. Since roots come in conjugate pairs, $\chi$ has at least two real roots. They are different because otherwise $\chi(x)>0$ for all $x$.